# Jenkins multibranch pipeline: how to get most recent git tag?

Tags: git, jenkins

My project build relies on git tags to determine the version to use for an artifact. I'm trying to create a Jenkins multibranch pipeline. That means, I need somehow to get an equivalent of the output of

`git describe --tags`

into my Jenkins pipeline. No matter what I do with all kind of "Advanced behaviors", I get a detached HEAD and git saying it has nothing to describe.

This document https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/ 
mentions `$class: GitTagMessageExtension` with an optional boolean parameter `useMostRecentTag`, which, by description should provide exactly what I need, but I cannot find the equivalent for it in pipeline snippet generator, and when, in Jenkisfile, I include

```
checkout(
            [$class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: '**']], 
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [
                [$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 0, noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false], 
                [$class: 'GitTagMessageExtension', useMostRecentTag:true]
            ], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'xxx']]
            ]
        )
```

I'm getting an error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class hudson.plugins.git.extensions.GitSCMExtension is named GitTagMessageExtension
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed by @ioannis-barakos, the GitTagMessageExtension plugin was missing. However, after installing it, the promise of

> If you ticked the Use most recent tag option, and the revision checked
>   out has no git tag associated with it, the parent commits will be
>   searched for a git tag, and the rules stated above will apply to the
>   first parent commit with a git tag.

doesn't hold. It just runs `git describe --tags <commit-hash>` against detached head and exports exactly nothing.

So, does anyone know how to handle it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It was all false alarm: I just forgot to `git push --tags`

There is one counter-intuitive catch, though: ticking "Discover Tags" is not enough, one has to also choose "Advanced clone behaviors" and tick "Fetch tags"

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have the `Git Tag Message Plugin` installed in your Jenkins.

The `GitTagMessageExtension` is provided by that plugin (as in [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-tag-message-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gittagmessage/GitTagMessageExtension.java))

Make sure that you have the following plugin installed in your Jenkins plugins.

[image: Git Tag Message Plugin]

Below is a working example that searches for tags in all branches (origin/**).
Have in mind that a credentialsId should have been configured in jenkins holding the username/password of the jenkins account and a `RelativeTargetDirectory` class should be set for the download/clone location.

```
script {
    checkout([
      $class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [[name: "origin/**"]],
      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
      extensions: [[
      $class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
        relativeTargetDir: "/tmp/jenkins/git"],
        [$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 0, noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false], 
        [$class: 'GitTagMessageExtension', useMostRecentTag:true] 
        ],
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[
             credentialsId: 'ioannis.barakos',
             url: 'https://git.example.com/git/example'
        ]]
    ])            
}
```

Comment: thank you, it doesn't fail now, but it runs `git describe --tags` against detached head and exports nothing (I've updated my answer)

Comment: Your tags are on branches? You can set your branch on `branches: [[name: '**']]`. Have you tried it? In my case I have tags in branches and it works.

Comment: Baracos: yes, I've tried this. Maybe I wasn't explicit enough: I need git tag even if the current commit is not tagged (that is, a tag from the parent branch with a suffix, like `0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-9-ga2c5058`).

Comment: Try to use  `branches: [[name: "origin/**"]]`  In my case, I can clone the most recent tag with that branch configuration. I added my pipeline script for reference

Comment: Happy to hear that you solved the second issue by pushing the tag. Good to know that my answer helped you solve your original question. You may also add your answer as a comment in my answer to help people with similar issues follow the same flow while troubleshooting their issue. I also expect to accept my answer :)